# OnsenUI checkiOS7 Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm using Onsen UI 1.0.3 together with PhoneGap/Cordova 3.3.1. I have an onsen list `<ons-list>` with some onsen items `<ons-list-item>` inside.

When I try to run the code on my Nexus 7 android tablet, I get the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Class.extend.checkiOS7 (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/onsenui_all.js:22059:23)
    at Channel.subscribe (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:733:11)
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:126:34)
    at Class.extend.checkiOS7 (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/onsenui_all.js:22065:15)
    at Channel.subscribe (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:733:11)
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:126:34)
    at Class.extend.checkiOS7 (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/onsenui_all.js:22065:15)
    at Channel.subscribe (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:733:11)
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:126:34)
    at Class.extend.checkiOS7 (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/onsenui_all.js:22065:15) <ons-navigator title="Suche" page="views/school-search.html" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

Seems to be this bug came with the new version and is related with the `checkiOS7` function of Onsen UI. A former version of Onsen UI worked well.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it's now fixed!
I post the link to this github issue for reference.

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/76